# maximum column value according to timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

Weekly data table

[image]

I want to get the sno and max value of weekly points but if the weekly_points of tow sno are same there will arise a problem. So I want to get the mx value and sno where the timestamp is minimum, I mean, the query which has been inserted earlier.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rank the rows according to descending weekly points and ascending timestamp, and pick the first row:

```sql
select serial, sno, weekly_points, timestamp
from (
    select *, row_number() over (order by weekly_points desc, timestamp) as rn
    from weekly_data
)
where rn = 1
```